# Let test know it can run once app has got to specific point - possibly sharedPref

Tags: android, libgdx, sharedpreferences, android-testing

tl;dr - Find a way to let a test know it can run, only once my game main menu has loaded

I am writing a game in LibGDX, which doesn't use Android code really, and I have a single test class, that I am using to test various visual aspects of my game.

I want to find a way of letting the test know that the game has loaded to the main menu before running tests.

I have tried to share a shared pref over the two apps, but haven't managed due to using SDK 25 and certain modes being deprecated.

Does anyone have any idea? I have thought of using the sdcard to save some sort of file, but every now and then (I'm testing on the emulator) the sdcard doesn't work (that's a whole other issue)

Comment: Confused by your question. There are two separate apps that need to communicate with each other or just two Activities, or what?

Comment: In LibGDX there is only one Activity, but when you run automated tests (or instrumentation tests, I'm a little lost as to which mine are) technically a new app is created that runs the test on the other app, so I need the test app to be able to see things from the real game app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://codexample.org/questions/57868/data-sharing-between-two-applications.c

I managed to get the dual shared pref stuff working with the below code

Send data from Application 1 (for ex:Application 1 package name is "com.sharedpref1" ).

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("demopref",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("demostring", strShareValue);
        editor.commit();
```

Receive the data in Application 2( to get data from Shared Preferences in Application 1).

```
try {
        con = createPackageContext("com.sharedpref1", 0);//first app package name is "com.sharedpref1"
        SharedPreferences pref = con.getSharedPreferences(
                    "demopref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String your_data = pref.getString("demostring", "No Value");
    } 
catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("Not data shared", e.toString());
     }
```

In both application manifest files add same shared user id & label,

```
android:sharedUserId="any string" 
android:sharedUserLabel="@string/any_string"
```

both are same... and shared user label must from string.xml

like this example.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.xxxx"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:sharedUserId="aaa.bbb.ccc" 
    android:sharedUserLabel="@string/any_string">
```

I had a small issue with the sharedUserId not working when I just had a single word, and apparently it needs to follow a packagename style format (the example I found had 3 sections to it, and this worked for me first time, so I didn't investigate anything else)

Comment: So you're using an OnSharedPreferenceChangedListener to treat this change like an event?

Comment: No, but I guess I could. I'm just using a while loop inside my test checking the value once a second, and having a counter inside so that it doesn't get stuck counting forever.

Comment: Great answer, much simpler than services. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

First I would highly recommend testing on real devices, I personally own 20+ test devices and they all cost below $20 each except a few high end models. The experience and feel is worth the money, but most importantly I believe there are things emulator can't do as well as a production model.

In your case, I think you need some sort of cross app communication to start testing?

1. Have you tried creating your own SQLite database and contentprovider in 1 app, making it public. Then having the 2nd app contentresolver and access data in the 1st app.
2. Create a bounded service, bound both apps to it, now inter process communication is possibly and very easy, read any of the millions of documentation on this, start here

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger

Comment: Thanks for your post, I've got a few questions...
1) really? $20?! where from!?
2) I'm only using them for visual screenshots at the moment, to see if everything fits on the screen etc, so I don't really need the 'feel' aspect
3) I'm going to look into this Messenger thing now, and if it's good and works I'll marks yours as the correct answer. However, I simply need a flag to trigger/be set, this seems like it might be a bit complex for that?

Comment: @Russ, yep and less than $20 for most devices android 6.0 and under. Simply search ebay for "used" "cracked screen" devices hehe. I mean we don't care about the condition of the phone, as long as its android works. In fact the worse condition, the better cause its cheaper. Regarding complexity, it sounds complex but services are actually really easy in android. give it a try and let me know :)

Comment: I managed to find a way to get the shared prefs working across two apps, so I haven't accepted your answer, but only because I didn't bother trying it. It's very probably right and will work, so I've upvoted it, but as I haven't *actually* tried it, I don't want to mark it as correct in case anyone else comes across this in the future and it doesn't actually work.

Comment: Nice! And no problem. You know you could answer your question with how you solved it, I'd learn from that and def up vote it :) I believe you can also mark your own answer as accepted in this situation.

Comment: Advice - stick with Google's devices, nexuses, since they are the only ones with native android. Used nexus 4 is under $100 now (android 5.x), used nexus 5 is slightly above $100 (android 6.x) and even for android 7.x and higher resolutions (2K resolution) you can find used nexus 6 i.e. for about $200.